# Cannot find custom keyword in robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to import custom keyword written in python into robotframework.

I got following situation:

Got file.robot with following content:

```
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library    ../../../python_scripts/mapActions.py

Drag and drop     //*[@id="map"]  -50     -50
mapActions.Drag and drop   //*[@id="map"]  -50     -50
mapActions.MapActions.Drag and drop     //*[@id="map"]  -50     -50
```

And mapActions.py:

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword

class MapActions(SeleniumLibrary):
   @keyword
   def drag_and_drop_on_element_with_offset(self, locator, x, y):
       map_locator = self.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
```

After running file.robot got output:

> 1) No keyword with name 'drag and drop on element with offset' found.
>
> 2) No keyword with name 'mapActions.drag and drop on element with
>   offset' found.
>
> 3) No keyword with name 'mapActions.MapActions.drag and drop on
>   element with offset' found.

Using Python 3.7.2
RobotFramework 3.1.1

Trying those three options cause not sure which one should be taken into account...

What I am doing wrong? Why file.robot cannot run 'drag and drop' function?

Comment: Try not using the `@keyword` annotation. Haven't extended the `SeleniumLibrary`, but the classes I create don't have the annotation in their methods and they are imported as keywords just fine.

Comment: It does not change anything here...
Only If I add method drag_and_drop_on_element_with_offset to mapActions.py then this method is found. 
But I need MapActions class to be found...

Comment: Try naming the module (file) *exactly* the same as the class (same casing): File: `MapActions.py`, class: `MapActions`.  Currently your  file has lowercase 'm'.

Comment: It does not help either... Tried it before

Comment: Dang..  I'm at a loss now.  I do think the file name and the class name need to be the same (case sensitive).  At this point, I would recommend doing that keyword as a Robot Framework keyword and not python, since what you're doing is pretty simple.  Then import as a _Resource_ rather than a _Library_.

Answer (score 0):

Only the exact function name can be used as a keyword name.

**In .py file**

```py
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword

class MapActions(SeleniumLibrary):
   @keyword
   def drag_and_drop_on_element_with_offset(self, locator, x, y):
       map_locator = self.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
```

**In Robot Framework file**

```
Library    <<File Path>>

drag_and_drop_on_element_with_offset     //*[@id="map"]  -50     -50
```

**Below is the working and tested example**
**Test_Suite.robot** robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ../../UUID.py 

*** Test Case ***
Create New License Model
    ${uuid}=                     Generate UUID
```

**UUID.py** python module

```py
def Generate_UUID(self):
        """generate a uuid"""
        return uuid.uuid4()
```